# Alternative to before </body> tag inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know inline Javascript is frowned upon and with the new on-the-fly [Javascript compressors](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) that check for idle/unused function usage and omit the unused code, it seems good practice to have all your Javascript in an external file.

My question is, in situations like [FOUC](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/) (*flash of unstyled content*) which usually require little snippets of code right before the closing `</body>` tag, is there a JQuery resolution that would serve the same purpose, but from a remote Javascript file linked in the `<head>` of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()) what your looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // anything in here will execute when the page has finished loading
});
```

Comment: drs9222 is exactly right, however inline Javascript has it's place to reduce the number of http requests. (which often max out at 2 per domain), because often a lot of wait time is the browser waiting for another pipeline to show up. This is especially true of home pages which often have a lot of one of a kind scripts that you don't care if they are cached. There are also good compressors that in addition to compressing your code, will inline it. Same with CSS.

Comment: @zen - The 2 per domain limit is only existent in IE still I believe, though it is to the specification, the other browsers left it behind some time ago.

Comment: @drs9222: That actually seemed to work, I already had most my code in the JQuery document ready wrapper and I added the Fouc prevention code right after it, it seemed to result in the same experience. 

@zenWeasel: That is true, luckily I only have one Javascript document to append aside from Jquery.